# Ensure consistent column widths when using heatmap with subplot2grid

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, subplot

I'm trying to format my subplots, but, for some reason, i can not figure out why the the position does not remains flat for all of them. Right now, they look like this:

[image]

As you can see, i have two issues: 1. i don't know how to exclude the text labels (like "dates") and 2. I need to format the subplots to share the same axis, so they remain aligned. My code so far:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25, 15))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((23,20), (0,0), colspan=19, rowspan=17)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((23,20), (19,0), colspan=19, rowspan=1)

sns.set(font_scale=0.95)

sns.heatmap(pivot, ax= ax1, annot=True, fmt=".0f", robust=True, linewidth=0.1, square=True, cmap="Blues")
sns.heatmap((pd.DataFrame(pivot.sum(axis=0))).transpose(), ax=ax2, annot=True, fmt=".0f", robust=True, linewidth=0.1, square=True, cmap="Blues", xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False)

plt.show()
```

My dataframe is this:

```
dates   2020Q1  2020Q2  2020Q3  2020Q4  2021Q1  2021Q2  2021Q3
inicio                                                        
2020Q1    56.0    45.0    15.0     7.0     4.0     4.0     3.0
2020Q2     NaN   418.0   277.0    86.0    46.0    33.0    28.0
2020Q3     NaN     NaN   619.0   398.0   167.0   122.0    93.0
2020Q4     NaN     NaN     NaN  1163.0   916.0   521.0   319.0
2021Q1     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   976.0   680.0   363.0
2021Q2     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   811.0   559.0
2021Q3     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  1879.0
```

Comment: Do you want the x and y tick labels (e.g. `2020Q1`)?

Comment: I just cant remove the labels from the figure. I mean, the labels "dates" and "inicio". The other part, is to keep both plots aligned...

Comment: The easiest way to match the subplots widths is to set `square=False`. labels can be removed with `ax1.set_ylabel('')`, and ticklabels can be removed with `ax1.set_xticklabels([])`

Comment: Maybe also rotate the yticklabels with `ax1.set_yticklabels(pivot.columns, rotation=0)`

Comment: Exactly what i needed. THanks man! Do you want to post it, so i can mark as resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Changing `square=True` to `square=False` in [`seaborn.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) will all the columns to have the same width.
- Labels can be removed by setting them as an empty string: `ax1.set(xlabel='', ylabel='')`
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `pandas 1.3.3`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
import panda as pd

# test dataframe
data = {'dates': ['2020Q1', '2020Q1', '2020Q1', '2020Q1', '2020Q1', '2020Q1', '2020Q1', '2020Q2', '2020Q2', '2020Q2', '2020Q2', '2020Q2', '2020Q2', '2020Q3', '2020Q3', '2020Q3', '2020Q3', '2020Q3', '2020Q4', '2020Q4', '2020Q4', '2020Q4', '2021Q1', '2021Q1', '2021Q1', '2021Q2', '2021Q2', '2021Q3'],
        'inicio': ['2020Q1', '2020Q2', '2020Q3', '2020Q4', '2021Q1', '2021Q2', '2021Q3', '2020Q2', '2020Q3', '2020Q4', '2021Q1', '2021Q2', '2021Q3', '2020Q3', '2020Q4', '2021Q1', '2021Q2', '2021Q3', '2020Q4', '2021Q1', '2021Q2', '2021Q3', '2021Q1', '2021Q2', '2021Q3', '2021Q2', '2021Q3', '2021Q3'],
        'values': [56.0, 45.0, 15.0, 7.0, 4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 418.0, 277.0, 86.0, 46.0, 33.0, 28.0, 619.0, 398.0, 167.0, 122.0, 93.0, 1163.0, 916.0, 521.0, 319.0, 976.0, 680.0, 363.0, 811.0, 559.0, 1879.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# pivot the dataframe
pv = df.pivot(index='dates', columns='inicio', values='values')

# create figure and subplots
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((20, 10), (0, 0), colspan=19, rowspan=17)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((20, 10), (19, 0), colspan=19, rowspan=1)

sns.set(font_scale=0.95)

# create heatmap with square=False instead of True
sns.heatmap(pv, ax=ax1, annot=True, fmt=".0f", robust=True, linewidth=0.1, square=False, cmap="Blues")
sns.heatmap(pv.sum().to_frame().T, ax=ax2, annot=True, fmt=".0f", robust=True, linewidth=0.1, square=False, cmap="Blues", xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False)

ax1.set_yticklabels(pv.columns, rotation=0)  # rotate the yticklabels
ax1.set(xlabel='', ylabel='')  # remove x & y labels
ax2.set(xlabel='', ylabel='')  # remove x & y labels

plt.show()
```

[image]